# Foreign Key в Doctrine (Symfony). Как привязать новый дочерний элемент к уже существующему родителю?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony5

Имеется база данных Регионов и Городов. Связь таблиц regions и cities - один ко многим. Ниже описан мой код, реализовывающий добавление нового города в базу. На него выдаёт ошибку:

[image: Exception]

Нашёл в интернете только одно решение - использовать $entity_manager->persist(); не только на городе, но также и на регионе. Но в таком случае Doctrine дублирует уже существующий в базе регион. В документации Symfony же рассматривается добавление нового дочернего элемента вместе с новым родителем, что мне не нужно.

**В контроллере:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/insert/city", name="city")
 */
public function city(Request $request)
{
    // Получаем список регионов
    $regions_in_database = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Regions::class)->findAll();

    //Записываем названия регионов в массив
    $regions = [];
    foreach ($regions_in_database as $region) {
        $regions[$region->getName()] = clone $region;
    }

    // Создаём форму
    $city = new Cities();
    $insert_city = $this->createForm(InsertCityType::class, $city, [
        'regions_array' => $regions,
    ]);

    // Проверяем наличие регионов
    if (!$regions_in_database) {
        $insert_city->addError(new FormError("Отсутствуют регионы!
            Пожалуйста, перейдите по ссылке /insert/region и добавьте соответствующий регион"));
    }

    // Отправка формы
    $insert_city->handleRequest($request);
    if ($insert_city->isSubmitted() && $insert_city->isValid()) {

        // Проверяем, есть ли уже такой город в базе
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Cities::class);
        $city_in_database = $repository->findOneBy(
            [
                'name' => $city->getName(),
                'region' => $city->getRegion(),
            ]
        );

        // Если есть, выдаём ошибку
        if ($city_in_database) {
            $insert_city->addError(new FormError('Такой город уже существует!'));
        }
        else {
            $entity_manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity_manager->persist($city);
            $entity_manager->flush();

            $city = new Cities();
            $insert_city = $this->createForm(InsertCityType::class, $city);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('insert/city/city.html.twig', [
        'insert_city' => $insert_city->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

**Класс формы:**

```
class InsertCityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('region', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => $options['regions_array'],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Cities::class,
            'regions_array' => null,
        ]);

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('regions_array', 'array');
    }
}
```

**Сама форма:**

[image: Form]

**Класс региона:**

```
/**
 * Regions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="regions")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Regions
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Класс города:**

```
/**
 * Cities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="cities", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="region", columns={"region"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Cities
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Regions
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Regions", inversedBy="cities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $region;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRegion(): ?Regions
    {
        return $this->region;
    }

    public function setRegion(?Regions $region): self
    {
        $this->region = $region;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в:

```
clone $region;
```

клон является новым объектом для UnitOfWork доктрины. Поэтому требует сначала сделать для него persist.